# Android: Knowing ahead of time what size an ImageView will be?

Tags: android, image, thumbnails, imageview

My application uses thumbnails downloaded from the internet. The thumbnails are generated by the server, and one specifies in the request what size the thumbnails should be. Is there a way for me to know, programmatically, while inside a ListAdapter's getView(), the dimensions of an ImageView inside the View that is returned, so my thumbnail comes perfectly scaled? I can always hardcode it, but I'd prefer not to.

Alternatively, is there some sort of listener or callback I can use to request the thumb once the View has been laid out?

EDIT: The ImageViews have fixed layout_height and layout_width, however, I'd want to reuse the same code for different parts of the app, which use different size images, which is why hardcoding is particularly bad.

Answer (score 0):

You won't know dimensions at the construction phase of the ImageView in getView.
(obviously convertViews are different).

I have gotten round this by creating a subclassed ImageView that implements the View.OnLayoutChangeListener onLayoutChanged method and triggers loading of the image 
via our resizer proxy (and via a local memcache).  Whether this is the most elegant way, I don't know but it works. It all seems ugly compared to iOS!

See also:

[Android: Finding size (resolution-wise) of a GalleryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785881/android-finding-size-resolution-wise-of-a-galleryview).