# Android: Finding size (resolution-wise) of a GalleryView

Tags: android, android-layout, height, gallery

I have a `layout` where the `Gallery` `height` is `WRAP_CONTENT (width is FILL_PARENT)` with bottom margin of `80dp`. This would leave `80dp` at bottom of screen for something else.

The problem is how can I find out exactly how many pixels do I have in the `height` of this `Gallery`? 
I need this in order to set the size of the `bitmap` in Gallery's `getView` (as I want each image to take up a full Gallery screen) Various devices should give me different height pixels...

Apparently when I query `Gallery.getHeight`, it returns zero.

Also, if the image itself is smaller than the Gallery view port, I want to scale it up. However `setScaleType(FIT_CENTER)` seems to only scale down (if image is larger than viewport) yet does not scale up? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gallery` is just another `View`, so any method defined for `View` will work. Use `myGalery.getHeight();`

From the `View` API reference page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

> Size, padding and margins
>
> The size of a view is expressed with a width and a height. A view actually possess two pairs of width and height values.
>
> The first pair is known as measured width and measured height. These dimensions define how big a view wants to be within its parent (see Layout for more details.) The measured dimensions can be obtained by calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight().
>
> The second pair is simply known as width and height, or sometimes drawing width and drawing height. These dimensions define the actual size of the view on screen, at drawing time and after layout. These values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width and height. The width and height can be obtained by calling getWidth() and getHeight().
>
> To measure its dimensions, a view takes into account its padding. The padding is expressed in pixels for the left, top, right and bottom parts of the view. Padding can be used to offset the content of the view by a specific amount of pixels. For instance, a left padding of 2 will push the view's content by 2 pixels to the right of the left edge. Padding can be set using the setPadding(int, int, int, int) method and queried by calling getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight() and getPaddingBottom().

---

### Update

Be careful when are you measuring it. If you use it on the constructor, the it will return zero since it was not drawn yet. Unless you are absolutely sure that the `GridView` will be visible by the time you measure it, you can measure by adding an `View.OnLayoutChangeListener` and implementing

```
public abstract void onLayoutChange (View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html

or overriding `protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)`

Comment: That probably was the case since the view is just being inflated when I measured those numbers and rightfully returned zero. It's a chicken and egg situation since I needed to send in the pixel data for a correct size. Yet I've kinda solved it by changing the layout XML to use FILL_PARENT on the Gallery's height. Apparently it's being calculated during compile time and now I can consistently obtain the needed 605 (and correctly so on other smaller screen emulators)  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

u can get the total height & delete 80px from it ie(your Gallery height)
get total height by this code

```
Display display;
display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
display.getHeight()
```

Comment: Is there any way to do dp arithmetic? For screens with lower resolution, 80dp does not equate to 80px...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions may dis will help or DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     wn=(WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);